# jQuery dialog: height always zero

Tags: jquery, dialog

I need to implement the jquery dialog into an existing backend. Here's my code for opening a dialog window:

```
$("#dlg").dialog({
    width   :   900,
    height  :   600,
    modal   :   true
});
```

This should be correct. The problem is that the dialog's height is always zero, it will only display the titlebar. I've also checked the CSS, there's no additional styles applied to `#dlg`.

I checked the dialog container markup using firebug and it shows `height: auto;` which seems to be the problem, it should be 600. Any ideas what could be wrong?

Comment: Can you also show us your markup?

Comment: Where is `height: auto;` defined in? In the `style` attribute or is it coming from some CSS class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To set height after initialisation:

```
//getter
var height = $( ".selector" ).dialog( "option", "height" );
//setter
$( ".selector" ).dialog( "option", "height", 530 );
```

For more info see: http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Dialog/dialog#options